# Matrix generation

Tags: matrix

I have a $2x2$ matrix $M$. $M$ has the following form:

```
M = {{a, bExp[-2ikz]}, {bExp[2ikz], a}}
```

$a, b, k - const.$

`z` is variable that takes values from the range `0, 10, 20, 30, 40 ......300`. I need `30` different matrices `M1, M2....M30` corresponding to the values of `z` - `0, 10, 20.....300` and then multiply those matrices. How can I do that with *Mathematica* ?

Comment: Don't define 30 variables... define one function `M[k_Integer] := {{a, b Exp[-2I k z]}, {b Exp[2I k z], a}}`, and call it as `M[1]`, `M[2]`, etc. Note that the imaginary quantity is `I`, not `i`. You also need spaces between variables – `kz` is different from `k z`. This is quite possibly a duplicate of several and will most likely be closed.

Answer (score 2):

I think the following codes are for your problem ;

In order to obtain the M[1], M[2],... M[30] matrices, you can define them as a function. Namely,

```
M[z_] := {{a, b*Exp[-2 I*k*10z]}, {b*Exp[2 I*k*10z], a}}
```

To product two matrices, you can use the `.` between two matrices. For example;

```
M[1].M[2]={{a^2 + b^2 E^(420 I),a b E^(-420 I) + a b E^(-840 I)}, {a b E^(420 I) + a b E^(840 I),a^2 + b^2 E^(-420 I)}}
```

where I is `i`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. Now how does the full codes look like? What kind of looping do I need here?

Comment: @Hpaudel, try `Array[M, 30, 1, Dot]`